# Построчная вставка в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, таблицы

Каким образом можно заполнить данными построчно таблицы mysql в phpmyadmin? У меня почему-то данные вставляются удвоенно (на скриншоте не одна строка, а 2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия первой кнопки вперед оно сгенерировало нижеприведенный sql запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так и кнопки "вперед" две.
можно по одной строке заполнять

Comment: @DrMcSheen по поводу кнопки Вперед смотри обновленную часть вопроса.

Comment: а значение в idcategory вставлял? и строку запроса можно править вручную